# No code completion or suggestions in IntelliJ when working with multi-gradle project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, autocomplete, code-completion

My folders are marked as source folders and all auto-completion settings are enabled.
If I open the sub-projects individually (as the root) in IntelliJ, code completion works fine.

However, when I open the main project in IntelliJ (containing multiple sub-projects with their respective gradle files) I get no code completion or suggestions at all, not even for locally declared variables.

Does anyone know what could be the issue? Perhaps there are some other best practices for working in multi-gradle projects that I am unaware of?

Tried:
-Invalidating caches
-Restarting IntelliJ
-Making sure not to be in power safe mode
-Enabling all auto-completion settings

Comment: Are subproject detected as project (have sourced roots marked accordingly) when they are opened under root project?

Comment: Any chance you could share some subset of your gradle files (esp `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle`) demonstrating what code you want to be completed and where it's not completing it?    Otherwise, it's shots in the dark like this:  Did you include `implementation project(":sub-project-1")` in your top level `build.gradle`?

Comment: question: is your 'main-project' a proper gradle multi module project ? see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have been related to the Java version, after using 11 instead of 8 Autocompletion came back. Dowgrading back to 8 removes  code completion completely.